# freetext search with full string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I provide a two word string like *hello world* in freetext search, it fetching data with **hello** string and then with **world** but not with *hello world*.

But i cant go for like operator.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(50)
    SET @var = 'hello world'
 select * from helloTable where freetext(ColumnName, @var)
```

Result:

first set of rows are fetched on 'hello' and second set on 'world', **but i need with full string**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding double quotes?

```
'"hello world"'
```